# Resolve "Property does not exist on type 'Vue'" error

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Typescript with Vuejs to build an application.  I have several stand alone components (.vue) files that I am importing into a Typescript (.ts) file.  In the Typescript file, I am importing Vue from the npm Vue library and then creating a new Vue to display my components.  The error that I am seeing is:

> Property x does not exist on type 'Vue'

My build system is Webpack with tsc.  Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

### main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Competency from '../components/competency.vue';

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    'competency': Competency
  },
  data:{
    count: 0
  },
  methods:{
    initialize: function(){
      this.count = count + 1; // Errors here with Property count does not exist on type vue
    }
  }
})
```

### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    //"outDir": "./build/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "./Model"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./CCSEQ",
    "./WebResources"
  ]
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Evaluations: './WebResources/js/main.ts'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'Evaluations.html',
            template: './WebResources/html/Evaluations.html'
        }), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'ExpenseUpload.html',
            template: './WebResources/html/ExpenseUpload.html'
        }), new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'WebAPI'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it is just a typo when creating this example, but aren't you just missing a 'this' in your setting?

`this.count = count + 1;`
should be 
`this.count = this.count + 1;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### you should make a declare for import *.vue file.

#### such as:

> vue-file-import.d.ts

```
declare module "*.vue" {
   import Vue from "vue";
   export default Vue;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem but with exporting a component.
Some vs code snippets create templates without necessary types like this below

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      x: "something",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    rename(name: string) {
      this.x = name;
    },
    
  },
};
```

The problem was I did not add [`defineComponent()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent) to export default. So should be

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      x: "something",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    rename(name: string) {
      this.x = name;
    },
    
  },
});
```

Make sure you are exporting the component with the `defineComponent()` function.

Comment: The above did not work for me. The `import { defineComponent } from "vue";` line gives the error: `Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'. Did you mean to use 'import defineComponent from "vue"' instead?`.

Comment: If you are using nuxt, use the compostion api for importing `defineComponent`. `import { defineComponent } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";`

Comment: @Dip Why does it still say `Property ... does not exist on type '{}'. ts(2339)` ? I am using `nuxt 2.15.8, @nuxt/types 2.15.8, @nuxt/typescript-build 2.1.0, @nuxtjs/composition-api 0.33.1` and I imported and used `defineComponent` with correct syntax. I used the `setup()` function that returns the refs and in template all the errors are shown as if there is not `<script>` at all. And yes, I didn't forget `lang="ts"`

Answer (score 10):

Adding another answer to bring together several things you may need to fix.

## Ensure you include the ".vue" extension in the filename being imported

While both

```
import Competency from '../components/competency';
```

and

```
import Competency from '../components/competency.vue';
```

may *compile* successfully, the second one will help avoid the error appearing in some IDE's such as VS Code.

## Add a shim typings file

As @May pointed out above, you need a file that imports and re-exports the type of "Vue". In @May's answer, it is named `vue-file-import.d.ts`, but elsewhere on the internet it is commonly called `vue-shim.d.ts`. Regardless of name, the content needed is the same:

```
// vue-file-import.d.ts

declare module "*.vue" {
   import Vue from "vue";
   export default Vue;
}
```

## Try different locations for the shim file

Originally I put it in `/src`. I found this had an odd effect. Sometimes it worked, i.e. the VS Code error messages disappeared; and other times it didn't, they reappeared. This happened dynamically as I moved around the project editing different files.

I later found the suggestion for a shim file of identical content, but to be placed in `/typings`. I tried this and it worked consistently. Other people seem quite happy with the `/src` location.

Answer (score 8):

Have the same issue.
solution is to add a return type on each computed variable.

Issue from this code, without return type.

```
      computed: {
containerClass() {
    return this.isLastChild
  }
```

add return type String.

```
  computed: {
containerClass(): String {
    return this.isLastChild
  }
```

Comment: I had all the properties referenced with `this` which resulted in the error `Property ... does not exist on type ...`. Adding the return type to a computed property fixed all those issues!

Comment: Make sure you add a return type to all computed props!

Comment: Adding return type fixes my issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

@sherwin water's answer help me a lot. I recognized that, once I added a `computed` field, the error appears. The solution is simple: add return type for the computed field.

```
// wrong
computed: {
  someThing() {
    const { a, b } = this;
    return a + b;
  }
}

// correct
computed: {
  someThing(): number {
    const { a, b } = this;
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Comment: as soon as i added the return type the obviously totally misleading error disappeared. thank you!

Comment: such a weird solution but this also solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to follow this page https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html and was getting the same TypeScript errors, I fixed it by casting the Vue instance to type any like this

```
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            currentRoute: window.location.pathname
        },
        computed: {
            ViewComponent() {
                return routes[(this as any).currentRoute] || routes['/']
            }
        },
        render (h) { return h((this as any).ViewComponent) }
    })
```

Comment: How could you consider that an improvement? What's the point of using TS instead of JS?

Comment: TypeScript gives you compile time errors instead of runtime errors because of the type safety. It also adds things js doesn't have like interfaces and union types. IMO it is much, much better than js.

Comment: That was not my question.. If you sparkle your TS code with casts "as any" then the type safety is void and the point of using TS is null.

Comment: That's true in this one small case, I don't think just because there are two "anys" in the main new Vue statement make it not worth using TS. This is Vue's fault for not having declaration files for this (I haven't looked at Vue in awhile though, they might have them now).

Comment: You need to define the computed properties return type like so:
`ViewComponent(): string[] {`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using class based components when using typescript ([have a look at this "Writing Class-Based Components with Vue.js and TypeScript"](https://alligator.io/vuejs/typescript-class-components/)). This is the only way to have type safe code and use autocomplete functionality of your IDE

You need to install [vue-property-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator)

Here is an example of class based component:

```
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  props: {
    prop1: { type: Number }
  }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  // This is how you define computed
  get myComputedRoute() {
     return this.$route.params;
  }

  @Watch('myComputedRoute')
  onPropertyChanged(value: string, oldValue: string) {
    // Do stuff with the watcher here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript & vue2, you should use `Vue.component` or `Vue.extend` to define component.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
const Component = Vue.extend({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems (especially in .vue files).  I did find that this seemed to fix the problem however.  Anywhere you import .vue files, change the ES6 style "import" to "require" instead.

So in your example, change:

```
import Competency from '../components/competency.vue';
```

to...

```
declare var require: any;
var Competency = require("../components/competency.vue").default;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors with vue 2.8.2 and Typescript 2.5.3. I fixed it by holding my Vue instance in a variable then giving it a type. This ensures TS will know about all Vue properties when you instatiate it using an options object.

```js
var VueApp: any = Vue;

var App = new VueApp({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
     return {
        count: 0
     }
  },
  methods:{
    initialize() {
      this.count = count + 1; // Should work now
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use any

use `Object.assign(vm, source);` instead

like

```
const source= {count: this.count }
Object.assign(this, source);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I'm using VS Code editor.

I've installed Vetur plugin on vs code, Vetur handles vue file as typescript file, so I've fixed it to edit settings.json file

Please find this file on your VS editor in your project root directory, then set change like the below
[image]

```
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": false
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode this was fixed for me by quitting VSCode completely and opening it again.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Typescript's generics. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

```js
new Vue<{ count: number }, { initialize: () => void }, {}, {}>({

  //...

  data:{
    count: 0
  },

  methods:{
    initialize: function() {
      this.count = count + 1;
    },
  }
});
```